# How to get the battery level in background and announce it?

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service, batterylevel

In my app, I want to get the battery level in the background because I want to announce it in the text to speech when the battery level is low or when the battery is full or at any level. I have used the broadcast receivers and can get the battery level but don't know how to get it in the background.
Anyone can help?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing that you want to achieve can be done via intent Service, if you dig in the docs you can find it yourself, here is the link [Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/training/run-background-service/create-service), This type of intent can be fired in the background and can be used to perform various simple operations such as yours, because they don't have any interface but rather just operations executed in background.

Also here is a video guide [Background Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MV2mB1Wev2c) which you can use for yourself to get battery percentage and announce it after a certain condition

**Edit 2:**

(Nothing Required in XML as this is a background process/operation)
This is a code to get the battery percentage and announce it using Text to speech in broadcast receiver,

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.text_to_speech;
import android.app.AlarmManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Intent intent=new Intent(this,myBackgroundProcess.class);
        intent.setAction("BackgroundProcess");
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,0,intent,0);
        AlarmManager alarmManger= (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManger.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,0,10,pendingIntent);//change this time based on your liking which will fire the intent

    }

}
```

customerclass- **myBackgroundProcess.java**

```
package com.example.text_to_speech;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.BatteryManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;

import java.util.Locale;

import static android.content.Context.BATTERY_SERVICE;

public class myBackgroundProcess extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private TextToSpeech mTTS;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(context.getApplicationContext(), new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int status) {
                if (status != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
                    int result = mTTS.setLanguage(Locale.US);

                    if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                            || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                        Log.e("TTS", "Language not supported");
                        
                    } else {

                        BatteryManager bm = (BatteryManager) context.getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
                        int batLevel = bm.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
                        if(batLevel==100 || batLevel<=10 || batLevel==50)
                        speak(context,batLevel);

                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e("TTS", "Initialization failed");
                    
                }
            }
        });

    }
    public void speak(Context context, int batlevel)
    {
        mTTS.setPitch(10);
        mTTS.setSpeechRate(1);
        String text=String.valueOf(batlevel);
        mTTS.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }

}
```

In Android Manifest Register the receiver and add intent filter to it as shown below (below application tag)

```
<receiver android:name=".myBackgroundProcess"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="BackgroundProcess"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

Comment: Thank you but i did it with registering the broadcast receiver in service and did what i wanted to do and it worked

Comment: I have updated the answer and provided the solution for you, you can call the broadcast receiver based on your likings, am calling it after certain intervals (10-30secs) and it announces the battery level only if it is 100, 50 or less then 10, also shown in the code.

Comment: thanks for the help  but i used foreground service instead of alarm manager and it worked and the rest i did the same.